# Installing Nagios3 plugins with out installaing smbclient using apt-get in ubuntu

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to install nagios3 plugins with out installing smbclient,samba-common on ubuntu using apt-get.Will skipping these files can cause problems in future.

Comment: Do you have to install via a package or can you install from source?

Answer (score 1):

SMB is used by Nagios for the plugins to check Windows machines. You can find the the details of the commands used in /etc/nagios-plugins/disk-smb.cfg.

If you don't want these you should install `nagios-plugins-basic` instead of `nagios-plugins`.